# 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x94,

Tags: django

I get the below error but im unable to debug it,

Error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /catalog/
Caught UnicodeDecodeError while rendering: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 787:       invalid start byte
```

All the errors are provided in the below link,

http://dpaste.com/765793/

This is a very simple code that I just render a html page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Index.html

```
{% extends "catalog.html" %}
{% block content %} 
     <h2>Welcome!</h2> 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Error message shows: `In template c:\python27\djangoprojects\ecomstore\preview\templates\index.html, can't decode byte 0x94 in position 787`. So what's in `index.html`?

Comment: {% extends "catalog.html" %}
{% block content %} 
     <h2>Welcome!</h2> 
{% endblock %}

Comment: Wasn't my answer good enough to be accepted..?

Answer (score 3):

index.html is most likely in a non-UTF-8 encoding, possibly ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252. A hex editor is a good thing to use in these cases to examine how the ö et.c. are stored.

If index.html where in UTF-8, an ö would correspond to two bytes, c3 b6. If it is ISO-8859-1, it will be a single byte f6.

To solve this, either recode the file in UTF-8 or choose the right codec.